# check if a value is increased in an array from api php

Tags: php

Hi There I am Actually Working With SMSGATEWAY.Me api The Value is Being returned in an array from the api i just wanted to do something like a notification if there is a new message from api are there any ways to do this can i check when the value in the array is increased?

Comment: Get the maximum ID from the array and save it. The next time you query the API, get the maximum value again. Check if this maximum is higher than the previous one.

Comment: well that's the same thing i thought i can use count to store the number of items in an array but don't you think that would be a performance killer?

Comment: Check if the API has a function that only returns items newer than a given ID or created after a timestamp. Then you should be able to use the previous ID or time.

Comment: well yes that's a good idea i can get current time and check it against the time from the api